# Is there a way I can access a macro from a dependency's dependency without explicitly including it?

Tags: macros, rust, reqwest

Reqwest is built on top of Hyper which includes a `header!` macro to create custom headers. Is there a way I can access the `header!` macro without explicitly including Hyper as a separate crate?

```
#[macro_use] extern crate reqwest;

header! { (XRequestGuid, "X-Request-Guid") => [String] }
```

> cannot find macro `header!` in this scope

Answer (score 0):

No, you must directly import a macro to be able to use it. This is the same behavior as functions, types, and traits.

See also:

- [Cannot use macros imported in a library in an executable that uses that library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32804217/155423)
- [Why must I use macros only used by my dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48132095/155423)
- [Cannot use the `doc!` macro from the mongodb crate in the scope of a sub sub module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45033782/155423)